# audio file and json file reading methods difference in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, audio

I find difficult to understand one methodological thing about javascript coding.
When in a script I want to read an audio file, I do it like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('theme.mp3');
audio.play();
```

It is simple, clear and works dynamically: I have an access to a file system from the site (is it true?).
But if I'd like to read a json file, which is substantially a text file, I have to write an AJAX request:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        //code
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

And also using jQuery we see the same but shorten thing.
Could you explain me, why I can read all the graphics, audio files etc, but to upload JSON file I have to do that request? How does this kind of communication between client and server work? Where is a difference? Why I can't just read the text file, like I did it above with `theme.mp3`?

Thank you so much.

UPDATE:
The most important thing: when I read the audio file as above, **the script is working nicely even if I open the html file from the computer**. At the same time the loading of JSON file **doesn't work until the page is opened from the localhost**. (I'm sorry if I use incorrect terms).

"Help me StackOverflow, you are the my last hope."

Comment: You do not have access to the file system.. when you make that Audio call you are telling the browser to do an HTTP request to the server to retrieve that resource. The same is for the XMLHttpRequest calls. You are not directly interacting with the server's file system

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you Patrick. But I see just one strange thing: the loading the mp3 file above worked when I lunched the script just opening the html file in a browser. The JSON file loading code was not working before the upload to the localhost (I was using node.js to do this). Hence there is a difference?

Comment: Ok that is a different issue than what i took your question to be asking. This is CORS at work. Using Audio(url) is loading a resource, and as such you do not get access to its contents (eg raw binary data). Since you do not get content access the process does not have to go through a CORS check. On the other hand when needing to get JSON you are needing to get access to its contents. So this has to pass through a CORS check. Ajax requests are not allowed for file:// urls which is the urls you are using when loading a page straight from your computer. It would be a security risk if allowed.

Comment: @PatrickEvans thank you so much Patrick!